# assign a LPWSTR to an existing wstring

Tags: winapi, type-conversion, wstring

I am looking for a way to copy the content of a LPWSTR to an existing wstring.
I've found a lot of examples to do the reverse but I am still looking for a way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot guarantee that `.c_str()` will render the same pointer after modifying the string, period (if that's what you're trying to do).

The correct way to assign a `LPWSTR` to a `std::wstring` object is to use `operator=()`, like:

```
std::wstring existingString = L"text";
LPCWSTR c_str = L"more text";
existingString = c_str;
```

But this is extremely simple; maybe you should elaborate on what you're trying to do if this doesn't cover it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is to save the allocation time, the std::wstring is good to do the right thing usually, but if you really absolutely must do this...

```
wcsncpy(&wstr[0], wsrc, wstr.size()-1);
wstr[wstr.size()-1] = 0;
```

I felt really dirty writing that. Note: this will NOT allocate space in the wstr objet. further, i guarantee it will blow up if wstr, in fact, is currently empty, so beware. it will only use whatever you already have there for storage. If you want/need more space then .resize() appropriately, but as I said before, the assignment operator for std::wstring will really do what you want if you just let it.

Comment: *exactly*. That would be the "just let it" part of that answer. Probably overkill to not only copy into an exiting wstring, but the actual *memory* of that existing wsting, which is what i wrote. Much safer to use the assignment op or .assign(), I completely concur.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
LPWSTR k = L"my string";
std::wstring ws(k);
```

or if you really have to assign to an existing wstring

```
 std::wstring existing;
 ....
 existing.assign(k);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing that is a hack and implementation dependent. The correct way is to **assign** the LPCWSTR to the wstring - the compiler will then make sure that the contents are correctly **copied** into the existing char buffer if it exists or first allocate it and then copy.

Comment: Agree it is a total hack. Completly disagree the *compiler* will make sure to copy into the existing buffer. The implementation of std::wstring will ensure that; the compiler is just building the opcodes.